# How Spring automatically creates/instantiate Repository<T, ID>

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

I would like to create something similar Spring do with Repository. I was thinking about java proxies https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/java-dynamic-proxies/runtime-interface-implementation.html
but seems that they have the implementation https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/cdi/JpaRepositoryBean.java but it's not clear to me how to instantiate it at run-time.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Possibilities: `java.lang.reflect.Proxy`, compile-time class generation (e.g. annotation processing), run-time class generation (i.e. compiling code and loading it at run-time, which can be made easier with libraries), or even a combination thereof. Each of those options will likely need something like the factory pattern as well as reflection in order to return the correct instances.

Comment: Ok..but how Spring is doing this?

Answer (score 0):

It uses Dynamic proxies. You intercept the invoked method of the proxy and generate queries based on its name. It would take the part after "by" in the name and map it to the entity fields. As a commenter said above, reflection would be used, made easier by libraries, like BeanUtils.

I had to write something of this sort once. You would need to take all the properties of the entity in a map, and match them. And I also used a template method - because first you get all properties in a structure like a map, then you performed the traversal and so on. I also used an iterator. However it didn't use any ORM :( so I had to kind of make an ORM too. Spring JPA uses Hibernate so all of the ORM logic is handled by it.